# Is it possible to share a HashMap between threads without locking the entire HashMap?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I would like to have a shared struct between threads. The struct has many fields that are never modified and a `HashMap`, which is. I don't want to lock the whole `HashMap` for a single update/remove, so my `HashMap` looks something like `HashMap<u8, Mutex<u8>>`. This works, but it makes no sense since the thread will lock the whole map anyways.

Here's this working version, without threads; I don't think that's necessary for the example.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let s = Arc::new(Mutex::new(S::new()));
    let z = s.clone();
    let _ = z.lock().unwrap();
}

struct S {
    x: HashMap<u8, Mutex<u8>>, // other non-mutable fields
}

impl S {
    pub fn new() -> S {
        S {
            x: HashMap::default(),
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4910ef11949fa6a2127165ce25faef5c&version=stable&mode=debug)

Is this possible in any way? Is there something obvious I missed in the documentation?

I've been trying to get this working, but I'm not sure how. Basically every example I see there's always a `Mutex` (or `RwLock`, or something like that) guarding the inner value.

Comment: In order to achieve thread safety, there is no way around it. You must have a guard around the entire type and not just it's underlying fields.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks! That's too bad, sadly. Inserting/removing happens very rarely to the map, it's like 99.9% updates only. That's why I thought I would just lock the single element in the map, and use some kind of other method to ensure that inserting/removing happens while there aren't any workers using the map. Back to thinking I guess.

Comment: @Shepmaster Forgive me if I'm stupid, but updating a single element in the map wouldn't still need a write lock? Or do you mean, that I should use a read lock up until I actually modify the map, and then upgrade it to a write lock? Considering the actual work's ~95% would be under write lock in this way anyway, should I just go ahead and use a `Mutex` instead to avoid the `RwLock`'s overhead?

Comment: Do your threads really spend a lot of time accessing the HashMap? Is it read-mostly?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't see how your request is possible, at least not without some exceedingly clever lock-free data structures; what should happen if multiple threads need to insert new values that hash to the same location?

In previous work, I've used a `RwLock<HashMap<K, Mutex<V>>>`. When inserting a value into the hash, you get an exclusive lock for a short period. The rest of the time, you can have multiple threads with reader locks to the `HashMap` and thus to a given element. If they need to mutate the data, they can get exclusive access to the `Mutex`.

Here's an example:

```
use std::{
    collections::HashMap,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex, RwLock},
    thread,
    time::Duration,
};

fn main() {
    let data = Arc::new(RwLock::new(HashMap::new()));

    let threads: Vec<_> = (0..10)
        .map(|i| {
            let data = Arc::clone(&data);
            thread::spawn(move || worker_thread(i, data))
        })
        .collect();

    for t in threads {
        t.join().expect("Thread panicked");
    }

    println!("{:?}", data);
}

fn worker_thread(id: u8, data: Arc<RwLock<HashMap<u8, Mutex<i32>>>>) {
    loop {
        // Assume that the element already exists
        let map = data.read().expect("RwLock poisoned");

        if let Some(element) = map.get(&id) {
            let mut element = element.lock().expect("Mutex poisoned");

            // Perform our normal work updating a specific element.
            // The entire HashMap only has a read lock, which
            // means that other threads can access it.
            *element += 1;
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));

            return;
        }

        // If we got this far, the element doesn't exist

        // Get rid of our read lock and switch to a write lock
        // You want to minimize the time we hold the writer lock
        drop(map);
        let mut map = data.write().expect("RwLock poisoned");

        // We use HashMap::entry to handle the case where another thread 
        // inserted the same key while where were unlocked.
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(50));
        map.entry(id).or_insert_with(|| Mutex::new(0));
        // Let the loop start us over to try again
    }
}
```

This takes about 2.7 seconds to run on my machine, even though it starts 10 threads that each wait for 1 second while holding the exclusive lock to the element's data.

This solution isn't without issues, however. When there's a huge amount of contention for that one master lock, getting a write lock can take a while and completely kills parallelism.

In that case, you can switch to a `RwLock<HashMap<K, Arc<Mutex<V>>>>`. Once you have a read or write lock, you can then clone the `Arc` of the value, returning it and unlocking the hashmap.

The next step up would be to use a crate like [arc-swap](https://docs.rs/arc-swap/0.4.5/arc_swap/), which says:

> Then one would lock, clone the [`RwLock<Arc<T>>`] and unlock. This suffers from CPU-level contention (on the lock and on the reference count of the `Arc`) which makes it relatively slow. Depending on the implementation, an update may be blocked for arbitrary long time by a steady inflow of readers.
>
> The [`ArcSwap`](https://docs.rs/arc-swap/0.4.5/arc_swap/type.ArcSwap.html) can be used instead, which solves the above problems and has better performance characteristics than the `RwLock`, both in contended and non-contended scenarios.

I often advocate for performing some kind of smarter algorithm. For example, you could spin up N threads each with their own `HashMap`. You then *shard* work among them. For the simple example above, you could use `id % N_THREADS`, for example. There are also complicated sharding schemes that depend on your data.

As Go has done a good job of evangelizing: *do not communicate by sharing memory; instead, share memory by communicating*.

Comment: Thanks for the good working example.  Would you elaborate "you can switch to a RwLock<HashMap<K, Arc<Mutex<V>>>>. Once you have a read or write lock, you can then clone the Arc of the value, returning it and unlocking the hashmap." ?  
Why "clone the Arc" can help locking shorter and safe ? 
Or would give an example for this improvement ?

- thanks a lot,

Comment: @Charlie木匠 cloning an `Arc` only involves copying a pointer and atomically incrementing a reference count — a very fast operation. The newly cloned value can be used in isolation and no longer requires that the `RwLock` be read-/write-locked.

Comment: @Shepmaster Can I ask why a `RwLock<HashMap<K, Arc<Mutex<V>>>>` in your 2nd example? If you have the same amount of read and write, `Mutex<HashMap<K, Arc<Mutex<V>>>>` would have the same effect while being a bit lighter in terms of memory.

Also, in your sharding example, instead of spinning the threads, you could have a `Vec<Mutex<HashMap<K, V>>>` and like you said, use something like `hash(key) % shards.len()` to retrieve the shard

Comment: (to clarify `Arc<Vec<Mutex<HashMap<K, V>>>>` could be shared across threads)

Comment: @Ervadac I'm sure a `Mutex` would be fine in certain workloads. As you suggested: *if you have the same amount of read and write*. That's not always true — some systems have 99.9% reads and 0.01% writes.

Comment: @Shepmaster If we assume that the hashmap keys never get updated and that only the values get updated, could we remove the `RWLock` to the hashmap and only keep the locks on the values? Would something like this be possible?

Comment: @jimouris sure, if you mean something [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=673df199dd4e1a4ff88968d1a4b836ce).

Comment: @Shepmaster whoa, that's neat! thank you

Comment: @Shepmaster I have another question since I'm more familiar with rayon parallelization. Is there a benefit of using the `thread::scope` instead of rayon?

Comment: @jimouris IIRC, Rayon is a thread _pool_ while `thread::scope` is not. Also there's all the cool features for Rayon's parallel iterators.

Answer (score 9):

Suppose the key of the data is map-able to a `u8`

You can have `Arc<HashMap<u8,Mutex<HashMap<Key,Value>>>`

When you initialize the data structure you populate all the first level map before putting it in Arc (it will be immutable after initialization)

When you want a value from the map you will need to do a double get, something like:

`data.get(&map_to_u8(&key)).unwrap().lock().expect("poison").get(&key)`

where the `unwrap` is safe because we initialized the first map with all the value.

to write in the map something like:

`data.get(&map_to_u8(id)).unwrap().lock().expect("poison").entry(id).or_insert_with(|| value);`

It's easy to see contention is reduced because we now have 256 Mutex and the probability of multiple threads asking the same Mutex is low.

@Shepmaster example with 100 threads takes about 10s on my machine, the following example takes a little more than 1 second.

```
use std::{
    collections::HashMap,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex, RwLock},
    thread,
    time::Duration,
};

fn main() {
    let mut inner = HashMap::new( );
    for i in 0..=u8::max_value() {
        inner.insert(i, Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));
    }
    let data = Arc::new(inner);

    let threads: Vec<_> = (0..100)
        .map(|i| {
            let data = Arc::clone(&data);
            thread::spawn(move || worker_thread(i, data))
        })
        .collect();

    for t in threads {
        t.join().expect("Thread panicked");
    }

    println!("{:?}", data);
}

fn worker_thread(id: u8, data: Arc<HashMap<u8,Mutex<HashMap<u8,Mutex<i32>>>>> ) {
    loop {

        // first unwrap is safe to unwrap because we populated for every `u8`
        if let Some(element) = data.get(&id).unwrap().lock().expect("poison").get(&id) {
            let mut element = element.lock().expect("Mutex poisoned");

            // Perform our normal work updating a specific element.
            // The entire HashMap only has a read lock, which
            // means that other threads can access it.
            *element += 1;
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));

            return;
        }

        // If we got this far, the element doesn't exist

        // Get rid of our read lock and switch to a write lock
        // You want to minimize the time we hold the writer lock

        // We use HashMap::entry to handle the case where another thread
        // inserted the same key while where were unlocked.
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(50));
        data.get(&id).unwrap().lock().expect("poison").entry(id).or_insert_with(|| Mutex::new(0));
        // Let the loop start us over to try again
    }
}
```

Comment: also known as `ConcurrentHashMap` in java.

Comment: 2 level of HashMap mutex, thanks for sharing.  Can it change first level of Mutex to RW lock and then read won't block read ?  only to use write lock when 2nd level id not exists.

Comment: For example: i.e. lock_map: Arc<HashMap<u8,RwLock<HashMap<u8,Mutex<usize>>>>>

Comment: yes, first level of Mutex to RW looks a good improvement.

Comment: This technique is sometimes known as sharding. If you know how many shards you want in advance you can make the outer container an array (or vector if not) - so your type becomes e.g. `Arc<[RwLock<HashMap<K, V>>; 8]>`. Then you save one hash computation and one indirection per lookup.    Note that for these to be efficient, your `u8` key needs to be evenly distributed based on your data, otherwise one container can become more full than others. This is how [`DashMap`](https://github.com/xacrimon/dashmap) works if anyone is looking for a ready-made solution.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you want to consider [`evmap`](https://github.com/jonhoo/evmap):

> A lock-free, eventually consistent, concurrent multi-value map.

The trade-off is eventual-consistency: Readers do not see changes until the writer *refreshes* the map. A refresh is atomic and the writer decides when to do it and expose new data to the readers.

Comment: `evmap` can be used in a fully consistent mode by refreshing after every write.

Comment: The write and flush are not atomic operations though so I do not believe this qualifies as "fully consistent" as a read request could still race against the flush itself right?

Comment: @jeremyong What makes you think it is not atomic? I couldn't find any information right now. In my understanding, it works by keeping two copies of the map: one for reading and one for writing. The writes are not atomic, but the swapping of the two references could be atomic.

Comment: @jonas When writing, the read map is not locked, so someone could issue a read before the flush is visible.

Comment: @jeremyong Yes indeed. It is lock-free and always consistent (because the writer decides when to sync), but maybe not up to date. This is what "eventual consistency" means here: Eventual consistent between writer and reader, but the data can always be consistent in itself if the writer does something sensible.

Comment: @jonas I wasn't responding to your answer but to ibraheem's comment that evmap can be used in "fully consistent mode" (which I believe to be erroneous)